# PyCharm code completion: hint for undefined object property

Tags: python, pycharm, phpdoc

How to hint an object property in PyCharm in similar way as phpDoc works in PhpStorm?

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0RD9.png

Is this possible using only special comments or IDE hints?

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8hRU.png

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not available in PyCharm. The closest you can come are to creating docstrings, but these docstrings need to be placed inside a `__init__` function, and thus, the `__init__` function has to have these arguments in its parameters.